# best way to program a progress bar for many methods

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Say I have a button: btnExecute

This button executes all these methods:

```
doAction1();
doAction2();
doAction3();
doAction4();
```

Each of these actions takes a couple of seconds.

How would I go about updating a progress bar as each of these methods are run?

I know I could go into each of them and just add pbExecuteProgress.value = 10 for example but I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

I also do not want to do something like this:

```
doAction1();
pbExecuteProgress.value = 30
doAction2();
pbExecuteProgress.value = 60
doAction3();
pbExecuteProgress.value = 80
doAction4();
pbExecuteProgress.value = 100
```

Is there ANY way I create a progress bar that goes up to 100 in value and is = to the progress of a method??

Comment: What is actually happening in your methods (DoAction1, etc)?

Comment: a wide variety of things. some of them have 1-4 loops in each. others have no loop and just some if statements. very very random. they are also not exactly how im showing in the question. they are more like "scattered"... meaning you'd have a method, then some code, then another method, and so on.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you the programmer have to declare what progress you are actually at when it comes to manipulating a progress bar.  you can do this statically, algorithmically (in a loop x + 1/i), or via some other method which returns a flat value...but it must be manually declared.  Its usually easiest to do exactly the way you say you dont want to.  If you want more granularity, you can pass the progress bar into the functions themselves for incrementing...but it will still be manually declared.

Comment: that would complicate things. i guess im gonna have to go with the way i really didnt want to do. its all good tho. thanks anyways :)

Comment: I had a similar requirement and here is how I accomplished what I wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11727026/100283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var actions = new List<Action> {doAction1, doAction2, doAction3, doAction4};

foreach(var action in actions)
{
   action();
   progressBar.Value += (progressBar.Maximum - progressBar.Minimum) / actions.Count;
}
```

if you wanted to customize the progress values:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<Action, int> 
{
     {doAction1, 30}, 
     {doAction2, 30}, 
     {doAction3, 20}, 
     {doAction4, 20},
};

progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Maximum = actions.Select(kvp=>kvp.Value).Sum();
progressBar.Value = 0;
foreach(var action in actions)
{
   action.Key();
   progressBar.Value += action.Value;
}
```

Declaration and creation of the collection of actions does not have to happen just before you loop through it. In fact, a strength of this pattern (a form of the Strategy pattern) is that new Actions can come from anywhere, both inside the current class and out.

Comment: nice! Im gonna be trying this out.

Answer (score 4):

When you "nest" progress, the outer method has to estimate how long each subroutine will take to execute, and divide up its 100% among the subroutines.

You can either do this arbitrarily, i.e. method one is 40%, method two is 25%, etc, or you can do a"dry run" to decide how much work each method will do. For example, if each method processes a number of files, the dry run would count the files without actually processing them, and you could then use the file counts for each method to allocate the range of the progress bar that apples to each method.

The dry run approach gives a more accurate result, but the pre processing required can take quite a long time, and thus make the overall task slower.

Once you have the range for each subroutine you can pass in their starting and ending percentages, and they can advance the progress appropriately.

A neat way to handle this is to create a progress manager class that deals with all the subtask scaling, which makes if easy to nest a whole subtree of calls, and pass only one object around them to handle the progress display.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it yourself, I'd suggest timing each one of the statements inside of each method as well as the entire method, throw all the times into an array, convert them to a percentage, and write em to a text file or something. Rinse and repeat, average em up, and then you'll have to add a bunch of `pbExecuteProgress.value = X` statements. I know you said you didn't wanna do that, but at least this way it'd be a really accurate representation of the progress.

Just a thought.

Also, I'm fairly sure there are third party tools that'll do this kind of thing for you. However, it will be inherently impossible for them to be as accurate as the method above.